# error TS2339: Property 'includes' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, firebase, promise

I'm having the following error:

> error TS2339: Property 'includes' does not exist on type '{}'.

when trying to check if a username is taken or not. (It's perfectly working when I comment this error, then start with ng serve and then uncomment it but i cant launch my serve with the error, that's why I used this trick)

Service:

```
isUsernameAvailable(){
    const users = [];
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      firebase.database().ref('users').orderByKey().once('value').then(snapshot => {
        snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
          if(childSnapshot.val().username){
            users.push(childSnapshot.val().username);
          }
        })
        resolve(users);

      })
    });


  }
```

Component:

```
async checkUsername(){
    const username=this.signupForm.get('username').value;
    const usernames =await this.authService.isUsernameAvailable();
    if(usernames.includes(username)){
      this.usernameAvailable=false;
    }
    else {
      this.usernameAvailable=true;
    }
  }
```

I saw some people having a similar error with type String[] and problem was in tsconfig with es2017, but I already have it:

```
"lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
```

Where am I wrong ?

Comment: Don't use `new Promise`. https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/34397

Comment: You should annotate your functions to declare what they actually return.

Comment: You should use `map()` & `filter()`.

Comment: Ok thank you @SLaks I'm ATM a beginner with promise, I'll try your advice. Should I delete my topic or can my question be usefull for someone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly in this case the use of `new Promise` is not necessary, you can just return the promise. Secondly you need to should correctly type `users` as `string[]` that will help with the return type inference.

```
isUsernameAvailable() {
    return firebase.database().ref('users').orderByKey().once('value').then(snapshot => {
        const users:string[]  = [];
        snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
            if (childSnapshot.val().username) {
                users.push(childSnapshot.val().username);
            }
        })
        return users;
    })
}
```

Comment: It's working fine thank you. The funny (silly ?) thing is I used a promise because I had some async problem and I thought I had to add a promise to use async/await...

Comment: `.once` returns a promise already, and we can chain things using `then`